# Why isn't rectangle black in HTML 5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Below is a simple HTML 5 page with a canvas tag.  On the canvas a rectangle is drawn in black, and black text is shown.  But for some reason, the rectangle is actually grey.  To make it black, I have to draw it 2 or 3 times on top of itself.  That seems to indicate there is some sort of alpha issue going on, but I don't know why that would be.

ALSO, the line width looks quite a bit more than 1px wide.... ?

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function draw()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
    if (canvas.getContext)
    {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        ctx.lineWidth = "1";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.strokeRect(100, 100, 50, 50); //appears grey

        ctx.font = "22px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillText("test", 120, 120); //appears black as expected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line looks fat and grey as it is overlapping pixels when it is drawn - i.e. your line straddles two pixels. If you change your code to:

```
ctx.strokeRect(100.5, 100.5, 50, 50);
```

You'll see a solid black line.

[image]

See this page for more information: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#paths

Comment: Ahhhh!  I find that a little odd since every other drawing system I've used is specified in pixels, ie (1,1) would indicate a pixel 1,1 and not location 1,1 which doesn't have a single pixel assigned to it.  Oh well, gotta go with the spec.  Thanks for the answer.