# html canvas drawing shows through

Tags: javascript, canvas

*I'm sure this question has been asked before I just can't find an answer to it yet.*

I want to erase part of a black rectangle by drawing another, white rectangle on top, but a lot of the original black rectangle shows through as if it is being averaged:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
context.strokeRect(10,20,20,30);
context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(250,250,250,1)';
context.strokeRect(20,20,10,30);
```

[js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VdGa6/)  What I want to see is a single black C on the left and an almost white rectangle next to it.  Instead I see the single black C, a grey reverse C and the almost white line in between the two:

[image: Image of what is desired outcome and what is currently observed]

Comment: Is real white not `rgba(255,255,255,1)`?

Comment: Yes you are correct @JanHommes but for the purposes of the question I had to choose something visible, hence "almost white" and `rgba(250,250,250,1)` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I thought it's because the box isn't black at all, instead it looks gray and with a little bit of alpha. So, after some googling I found this: [Why isn't rectangle black in HTML 5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629996/why-isnt-rectangle-black-in-html-5-canvas)

basically, you draw you rectangle with a 1px wide border on a round pixel number, this means that the browser tries to draw on a half pixel. You should set the position to something .5 in order to avoid this problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/VdGa6/2/

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
// context.globalAlpha = 1;  // this is the default so it's not needed
// context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';  // this is the default so it's not needed
context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
context.strokeRect(10.5,20.5,20,30);
context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(250,250,250,1)';
context.strokeRect(20.5,20.5,10,30);
```

Comment: Great answer, didn't know that. Alternative you can set `context.lineWidth = 2;` and you get a bigger line that is displayed correct.

Comment: I didn't know it either, learned something new :) . Yes that would be another solution. I'll have to keep this in mind the next time I work with <canvas>

Comment: Jonas, I think you're about to get a lot of points for this answer... it's problem that seems to trip up so many people.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could also do a initial `context.translate(0.5, 0.5)` to move the whole grid. This way you don't need to adjust the integer coordinates for the other methods.

Comment: One also have to take zoom-level into account. If zoom-level is for example 90% one will get blurred lines on ca x5-x7 with translation set to 0.5